# Disk Utility not letting me partition my SSD or modify the current ones

Tags: ssd, disk-utility, partition, core-storage

Just yesterday I finally got my hands on a MacBook Pro in which I was planning to install Ubuntu and Windows aside from OS X for studying purposes.
I was barely beginning by partitioning the disk, or at least attempting to do so and found myself not being able to take advantage of most functions of Disk Utility like in the picture below:

[image: Screenshot]

I've already tried a couple of tutorials and even tried to apply some solutions to problems that seemed similar, but nothing worked.

Comment: In the picture it says "You may only split this partition into two. To do this. click +." and the + button does not appear to be grayed out.  So what happens when you click it?  Also, since it's using a **Logical Volume Group** I'd forgo partitioning and just run Ubuntu and Windows in a Virtual Machine since it for study purposes.

Comment: You can only get max 4 partitions on an LVG drive, inc hidden ones. For anything more, it's down into some nasty terminal. Also, trying to add Windows without using Boot Camp itself to do it is really to be avoided. Golden rule - don't let anything other than Mac attempt to adjust partitions.

Answer (score 2):

You have several possibilities to repartition your CoreStoraged drive:

- You may resize the Logical Volume Group non-destructively with [diskutil](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/diskutil.8.html)
  `diskutil cs resizeStack LVUUID size`. You get the LVUUID with `diskutil cs list`
- You may revert the Logical Volume Group to a native volume
  `diskutil coreStorage revert LVUUID` and check and resize the volume afterwards with `diskutil resizeVolume DiskIdentifier limits` and `diskutil resizeVolume DiskIdentifier size`. You get the DiskIdentifier with `diskutil list`.
- Create new partitions with [gpt](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/gpt.8.html)

After repartitioning your SSD like that you won't be able to set-up Windows 7/8 with the default Boot Camp Assistant MBR-based method.

Most of the methods to [efi-dual-boot](http://www.reddit.com/r/mac/comments/2fy3be/by_popular_demand_my_better_than_bootcamp_guide/)/triple-boot/[quadriple-boot](https://racerrehabman.wordpress.com/2012/07/06/guide-to-installing-windows-7-windows-8-mac-os-x-lion-and-ubuntu-multi-boot/) require to completely erase of your SSD.

As already mentioned in the comments consider using Parallels/VMware Fusion and setting up virtual machines.