# How to restore Mac partition

Tags: macbook-pro, partition, disk-format

I'll preface this question with the obligatory "I did something stupid"...

I wanted to factory restore my 2012 MacBook Pro.  I did Command-r, and later Command-Option-r, but both times Reinstall macOS failed after a while.  (I did not write down the exact failures but, in hindsight,  it may have been connectivity problems).

I then went into Disk Utility and saw Restore.
I guessed that restoring from "OS X Base System" into my main partition would at least take me back to the original OS version and I could upgrade from there.

Apparently, I was wrong.

Regular reboot now takes me into macOS Utilities and Disk Utility shows that my disk now has just one partition, a 500GB "OS X Base System".

I can't do a Reinstall OS since the only partition is in use, and I can't shrink the partition either.

Do I have any way forward from here?  (If it helps: I have other computers here and various USB drives. But I don't have any other Macs).

Comment: There's a lot of similar questions with answers already.  Have you searched the site to find what's worked for others?

Comment: I tried searching but didn't find anything that matched this situation exactly.  (I'm something of a Mac noob; quite possible that I missed something that looked superficially different to me).  If you see anything that matches, please point me to it.  (Thanks!)

Comment: No problem, I just didn't want you to wait for an answer if there was one already out there.  Hopefully you'll get a good answer soon.

Comment: Take a look at [this question and answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/174125/88313).  It looks similar to me but only you can tell for sure.

Comment: I think I've found the answer. I had been faked out. When I rebooted, it did the equivalent of a Command-r.  I now did a Command-option-r, and I've made it past the problem.

It still remains to be seen if I can get past the original problem of the installation failing an hour later.  But, at least I'm past this issue.
Thanks for pushing me to look harder!

Comment: All good now. Machine is rebuilt, up and running

Comment: I'm glad to see that!

Answer (score 1):

I was ignorant. I simply needed to use <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>Option</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd>.